# Wifi connected on lubuntu 17.04 but no internet

Tags: networking, lubuntu

hello I am booting lubuntu 17.04 from a usb. I am able to connect to my wifi at home but Firefox shows "server not found"  and my synaptic package manager only shows "failed" when i try and get packages.  I went to a friends house and booted from my usb and was able to connect to the internet via wifi and everything was working fine.  I should mention that I am using an hp pavilion 360 and it has no ethernet connections.  Is there something I should change on my router to remedy this?  Thank you for your time and patience.

Comment: It sounds like you are connecting to your home wi-fi just fine, but your home router is not connected to the Internet.  This could be an issue with your router (usually easy to fix by un-plugging and re-plugging your router and your cable/dsl/fiber-optic modem).  This may also be an issue with your ISP.  Are you able to connect to the internet using a different computer on the same wireless SSID?

Comment: my phone will connect